# Jmeter: Ultimate Thread Group - Test finishes before it should

Tags: jmeter

I am using 'Ultimate thread Group' scenarios for each of my 7 scripts/scenarios (each thread group having different number of users). For each of them, i have given the same 1800s as ramp-up and 3600s for steady-state and 90s for ramp-down.

I expect the test to run for about 1.5 hours whereas it finishes in 55min. Any suggestions please?

Thanks,
N

Comment: Is this thread group deprecated? What factors could shorten the duration of the test? What is the alternative thread group I can use

Answer (score 0):

You can check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it contains the reason for the ending each and every thread.

I can think of the following possible reasons for premature ending the test and none of them is specific to the Ultimate Thread Group:

1. You have chosen something other than "Continue" or "Start Next Thread Loop" under "Action to be taken after a Sampler error":

   [image]
2. You have [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) which is set up to stop thread at the end of the CSV file and you don't have sufficient amount of test data

   [image]
3. You're stopping the tread/test somewhere using [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler
4. Your test terminates as the result of an [OutOfMemory error](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling)

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. I have used option-3 you listed above. So this thread group is a valid one and not deprecated. right?

Comment: To my knowledge it is not, however it's a **plugin**, officially JMeter provides "normal" [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and since [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) [Open Model Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Open_Model_Thread_Group)